# Как подобрать признаки, которые влияют на целевую переменную больше других?

Tags: python, анализ-данных, feature-engineering

У меня есть данные без описания (категориальные и непрерывные признаки) и целевая переменная (класс: 0 или 1). Мне необходимо отобрать признаки, которые лучше всего подходят для описания целевой переменной.

Как вариант решения, кажется интересным следующее:

1. Посчитать метрику на полном наборе данных.
2. По очереди исключать по одному признаку, подсчитывая метрику без него.
3. Отбросить все признаки, без которых метрика возросла.
4. Перейти к пункту (1). Повторять пока количество признаков не перестанет уменьшаться.

На первый взгляд, как минимум, кажется довольно сомнительным, что мы подсчитываем метрику с отсутствием одного признака, но исключать будем несколько за раз. Исключать сразу после подсчета, тоже не верно — так как в этом случае следующий признак будет подсчитан не на полном наборе данных.

Как правильно построить подобный алгоритм, чтобы учесть взаимное влияние признаков на целевую переменную?

Comment: Можете выложить пример обучающего набора данных?

Comment: @MaxU [Все те же данные, как и ранее.](https://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup/view/kdd-cup-2009/Data)

Comment: Какую цель вы преследуете? Уменьшение числа признаков?

Comment: Возможно стоит воспользоваться чем то вроде RFECV https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html

Comment: @MaxU (Извиняюсь за задержку с ответом, перемещался.) Есть предположение, что не все данные полезны для модели (например, среди категориальных могут быть закодированные ФИО). Из за большого количества признаков итоговое пространство признаков получается довольно большим. Хочу уменьшить, выбрав наиболее полезные признаки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробовал несколько способов подбора параметров. Как оказалось, мой «наивный» подход показал лучший результат *на моих данных*, потому что:

- Методы основанные на деревьях задают важность признаков, но не оптимальный набор.
- Методы рекурсивного исключения принимают на вход «алгоритм», который будет использован для построения модели. В случае категориальных данных и логистической регрессии мы передаем очень много созданных «dummy» признаков.

Я же искал метод, который найдет набор признаков, которые дадут лучший результат. Как оказалось, этот набор отличается от первых наиболее «важных» N признаков.

---

Ниже пример кода некоторых способов, которые я попробовал:

#### Простой перебор

`prepare_data_to_process` —  преобразует кат. данные, использует RobustScaler для вещественных и т.д. На выходе pd.DataFrame и имена используемых признаков, разделенные по типу.

```
def test_feature_set(data_categorical, data_numerical, y):
    X, numeric_cols, categorical_cols = prepare_data_to_process(
        data_categorical, data_numerical,
        data_categorical.columns, data_numerical.columns
    )
    if X.shape[0] == 0 or X.shape[1] == 0:
        return [-1.]
    return cross_val_score(LogisticRegression(), X, y)

def leave_only_best(data_categorical, 
                    data_numerical, 
                    cat_columns, 
                    num_columns,
                    labels):    

    baseline = test_feature_set(
        data_categorical[cat_columns], 
        data_numerical[num_columns], 
        labels
    )
    current_feature_num = len(cat_columns) + len(num_columns)
    print "\r\n\r\nBaseline: ", np.mean(baseline), "feature num:", current_feature_num
    num_result_set = list()
    cat_result_set = list()

    for index in range(len(num_columns)-1):
        columns = num_columns[:index] + num_columns[index+1:]        
        scores = test_feature_set(
            data_categorical, 
            data_numerical[columns], 
            labels
        )
        num_result_set.append((
            num_columns[index],
            scores
        ))
        print "Without %s:" % num_columns[index], np.mean(scores)

    for index in range(len(cat_columns)-1):
        columns = cat_columns[:index] + cat_columns[index+1:]
        scores = test_feature_set(
            data_categorical[columns], 
            data_numerical, 
            labels
        )
        cat_result_set.append((
            cat_columns[index],
            scores
        ))
        print "Without %s:" % cat_columns[index], np.mean(scores)

    new_num_columns = list()
    new_cat_columns = list()
    for column, scores in num_result_set:
        if np.mean(baseline) >= np.mean(scores):
            new_num_columns.append(column)        
    for column, scores in cat_result_set:
        if np.mean(baseline) >= np.mean(scores):
            new_cat_columns.append(column)  

    new_feature_num = len(new_num_columns) + len(new_cat_columns)
    new_baseline = test_feature_set(
        data_categorical[new_cat_columns], 
        data_numerical[new_num_columns], 
        labels
    )

    if np.mean(new_baseline) < np.mean(baseline):
        return num_columns, cat_columns
    if new_feature_num < current_feature_num:
        return leave_only_best(
            data_categorical, 
            data_numerical, 
            new_cat_columns, 
            new_num_columns,
            labels
        )
    return new_num_columns, new_cat_columns

def find_optimal_feature_set(scoring):
    data_categorical, data_numerical, y = load_and_split()

    return leave_only_best(
        data_categorical, 
        data_numerical, 
        data_categorical.columns.tolist(), 
        data_numerical.columns.tolist(),
        y
    )

num_columns, cat_columns = find_optimal_feature_set(scoring)
```

#### Поиск признаков, которые вносят наибольший вклад с помощью `ExtraTreesClassifier`.

[Код заимствован из спавки scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html)

```
def most_important_features():
    data_categorical, data_numerical, y = load_and_split()
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    data_categorical = data_categorical.apply(lambda x: encoder.fit_transform(x)).astype('str') 
    data_categorical = fill_missed_categorical(data_categorical).astype('category')
    X = data_numerical.join(data_categorical) 
    forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=250,
                                  random_state=0)

    forest.fit(X, y)
    importances = forest.feature_importances_
    std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in forest.estimators_],
                 axis=0)
    indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
    print("Feature ranking:")
    for f in range(X.shape[1]):
        print("%d. feature %s (%f)" % (f + 1, X.columns[indices[f]], importances[indices[f]]))
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
    plt.title("Feature importances")
    plt.bar(range(X.shape[1]), importances[indices],
           color="r", yerr=std[indices], align="center")
    plt.xticks(range(X.shape[1]), [f for f in range(1, X.shape[1]+1)])
    plt.xlim([-1, X.shape[1]])
    plt.show()

    return indices, importances, X.columns

indices, importances, columns = most_important_features()
```

Должно получиться что–то вроде такого:

[image: Важность признаков]

Ваше изображения будут прономерованные имена признаков с численным «вкладом». По графику можно выбрать «диапазоны» важности, после чего в цикле добавлять признаки и смотреть как меняется время работы алгоритма и итоговый результат.

#### RFECV — рекурсивное исключение признаков

Позволяет отсортировать признаки по их важности (группами!)

```
def test_rfecv():
    data_categorical, data_numerical, y = load_and_split()

    X, dummy_train, scaler, numeric_cols, categorical_cols = prepare_data_to_process(
        data_categorical, data_numerical,
        [], data_numerical.columns
    )
    print "result data:", X.shape

    selector = RFECV(LogisticRegression(), cv=get_cv(), scoring=scoring)
    selected = selector.fit(X, y)
    return selector, selected, X.columns

selector, selected, select_columns = test_rfecv()
for item in zip(select_columns, selected.ranking_):
    print item
```

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то говоря, вопрос отбора признаков -  не такая уж простая задача, как кажется. 
Кстати, в англоязычной литературе эта задача называется "feature selection".

Ваше решение, как одно из наиболее простых и интуитивных - имеет право на жизнь ("красиво" она описана вот тут - http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/images/2/21/PZAD2017_09_featureselection.pdf). Если же вы хотите более глубоко или математически корректно отбирать признаки, то в первую очередь надо понять - а зачем? Вариантов - несколько. Например - упрощение или вернее сокращение времени на обучение, снижение риска переобучения, повышение точности (т.к. наличие неинформативных признаков ее снижает) и пр. Далее надо понимать, сколько у вас признаков изначально - десяток (например, в мед.диагностике) или десяток тысяч(в классификации изображений. В анализе текстов - там свой, особый  случай. Естественно, надо понимать, у вас задача классификации или кластеризации, и.т.д. Для каждого случая свои методы, подходы и единого варианта решения - тем более, в отрыве от семантики задачи - не существует.

Обзор современных методов отбора признаков можно найти вот тут:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/user/login?returnURL=/getaccess/pii/S0045790613003066

или тут:

http://www.mathnet.ru/links/3a35d35d65879c35692c5cfa56af64af/ia429.pdf

Вот тут, описание проблем с неплохим "roadmap" для исследователя:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/an-introduction-to-feature-selection/

У Воронцова есть отдельная лекция по теме:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4qKbFd25Sk

Тут тоже вроде неплохо изложен материал:

https://ru.coursera.org/lecture/unsupervised-learning/odnomiernyi-otbor-priznakov-t0xdz

Неплохой обзор и описанием инструментов - тут:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/user/login?returnURL=/getaccess/pii/S0045790613003066

Ну, и я оставил за скобками Метод главных компонент, который также может использоваться говоря математическим языком - для понижения размерности признакового пространства, а говоря человеческим языком - специального сокращения количества признаков.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Посмотрел презентацию про подбор признаков. Она очень интересная, хотя, мне бы очень помог пример реализации всего того, о чем в ней идет речь.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш подход кажется мне вполне рабочим если исключить [мультиколлинеарность признаков](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) и если в качестве метрики вы планируете обучать и проверять модель для каждого набора столбцов. Как указано в [некоторых ссылках из ответа @passant](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/952679/211923) - "удачные" наборы признаков могут отличаться для разных алгоритмов классификации.

Поэтому многие методы из [sklearn.feature_selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_selection) ожидают `estimator` (в вашем случае объект соответствующего классификатора) в качестве входного параматра.

В этом может помочь [sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel), который в качестве `estimator` принимает любой алгоритм у которого после обучения модели присутствует атрибут `feature_importances_` или `coef_`.